# How to partition Gobblin output to 30 min partitions?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, camus, gobblin

We are planning to migrate from Camus to Gobblin. In Camus we were using below mentioned configs:

```
etl.partitioner.class=com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner
etl.destination.path.topic.sub.dirformat=YYYY/MM/dd/HH/mm
etl.output.file.time.partition.mins=30
```

But in Gobblin we have configs as:

```
writer.file.path.type=tablename
writer.partition.level=minute (other options: daily,hourly..)
writer.partition.pattern=YYYY/MM/dd/HH/mm
```

This creates directories on a minute level, but we need 30 min partitions.

Couldn't find much help in the official doc: http://gobblin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous/Camus-to-Gobblin-Migration/

Are there any other configs which can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Got a workaround by implementing a partitionerMethod inside custom WriterPartitioner :

While fetching the record level timestamp in the partitioner we just need to send the processed timestamp millis using below mentioned method.

```
public static long getPartition(long timeGranularityMs, long timestamp, DateTimeZone outputDateTimeZone) {
    long adjustedTimeStamp = outputDateTimeZone.convertUTCToLocal(timestamp);
    long partitionedTime = (adjustedTimeStamp / timeGranularityMs) * timeGranularityMs;
    return outputDateTimeZone.convertLocalToUTC(partitionedTime, false);
}
```

Now partitions are getting generated at required time granularity.